# Search string and print 3 lines after line containing string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data like this:

```
  direct vectors
 10.950000000  19.950000000  0.000000000     0.256410256  0.256410256 -0.256410256
 0.000000000  31.950000000  15.950000000    -0.256410256  0.256410256  0.256410256
 51.950000000  0.000000000  17.950000000     0.256410256 -0.256410256  0.256410256


 direct vectors
 1.950000000  1.950000000  0.000000000     0.256410256  0.256410256 -0.256410256  #print this line
 0.000000000  1.950000000  1.950000000    -0.256410256  0.256410256  0.256410256  #print this line
 1.950000000  0.000000000  1.950000000     0.256410256 -0.256410256  0.256410256  #print this line

 length of vectors
  0.50000000  0.50000000  0.50000000       0.007
  0.48979592  0.48979592  0.48979592       0.007
  0.47959184  0.47959184  0.47959184       0.007
  0.46938776  0.46938776  0.46938776       0.007
```

I would like to print the last 3 lines after the line which contains 'direct vectors'. My code does not work:

```
op_file = open(filename, 'r')
data_lines = op_file.readlines()
re_vectors = re.compile("direct vectors")
i = 0
for line in data_lines:
    if re_vectors.search(line):
        matrix = []
        for j in range(0, 3):
            parameters = data_lines[i+j+1].split()
            A = [float(parameters[0]), float(parameters[1]), float(parameters[2])]
            matrix.append(A)
        print(matrix)
```

I would like to have Output like this:

```
     1.950000000  1.950000000  0.000000000
     0.000000000  1.950000000  1.950000000
     1.950000000  0.000000000  1.950000000
```

Many thank!

Comment: Your second to last line is ..append where it should only be .append

Comment: You said you code doesn't work - what incorrect output or error message do you get?

Comment: it prints out 3 first lines of the file. It does not print 3 lines after the line containing the string 'direct vectors'.

Comment: The first three lines of numbers are *also* appearing after a line that says 'direct vectors'. Why don't you want those lines instead? What is the *real* rule that tells you what lines to print?

Comment: The code fragment doesn't define `re_lattice` - was that meant to say `vectors.search(line)` ?

Comment: In addition to @KarlKnechtel question, you say print line, but actually you print just first 3 numbers on each line - why?

Comment: Also `i` is not defined and never changes - you would always print the same lines.  Please post all the code used.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Three first columns of three lines present three vectors I need to extract. The rule is after each iteration, the major code will print out direct vectors after the line contains the string 'direct vectors'. And I need a final one. When I can search print three lines I need, then I use the "split" command to easily get the data I want. The problem here is my code does not show three lines after 'direct vectors'.

Comment: @Mike, thank. I edited the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never changes `i` so always prints the same lines.
Try incrementing `i` like this:

```
op_file = open(filename, 'r')
data_lines = op_file.readlines()
re_vectors = re.compile("direct vectors")
i = 0
for line in data_lines:
    if re_vectors.search(line) is not None:
        matrix = []
        for j in range(0, 3):
            parameters = data_lines[i+j+1].split()
            A = [float(parameters[0]), float(parameters[1]), float(parameters[2])]
            matrix.append(A)
        print(matrix)
    i++
```

Your code will still print both sets of three lines (one set after each 'direct vectors').  This is different to the description in your question.  If you only want the second set of three lines (as per your example output), then the answer by @balderman is better and has code that is much easier to follow and will work if you change the `print(l)` to:

```
parameters = l.split()
print(' '.join(parameters[0:3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()][1:]
    start_index = lines.index('direct vectors')
    lines_sub_set = lines[start_index + 1: start_index + 4]
    for l in lines_sub_set:
        print(l)
```

Comment: OP only wants the first 3 numbers of each line to be printed